# Rearange matlab struct

Tags: matlab, struct

Lets have a `struct` defined like this:

```
s.a = [1, 11]; 
s.b = [2, 22];
```

How can I convert it to struct defined like this:

```
s(1).a = 1;
s(1).b = 2;
s(2).a = 11;
s(2).b = 22;
```

This need comes from `textscan()` function. I read large file using this function and then convert the result using `cell2struct()` function. In this case, however, each field contains whole column, so one has to address individual value by `s.column_name(row_index)`. While I would prefer to do it by `s(row_index).column_name`.

Answer (score 3):

This type of operation with a [`struct`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) array does not usually result in pretty code, but here it goes:

```
s2 = cell2struct(num2cell(cell2mat(struct2cell(s))).', fieldnames(s), 2);
```

In general, indexing a `struct` array across its two "dimensions" (fields and array index) is problematic for this reason. Have you considered **using a [`table`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) instead**? It allows both types of indexing in a natural way:

```
s = table; % initiallize as table
s.a = [1; 11]; % note: column vectors
s.b = [2; 22];
```

So now

```
>> s
s =
  2×2 table
    a     b 
    __    __
     1     2
    11    22
>> s.a
ans =
     1
    11
>> s.a(2)
ans =
    11
>> s(:, 'a') % note: gives a (sub)table
ans =
  2×1 table
    a 
    __
     1
    11
>> s{:, 'a'} % same as s.a
ans =
     1
    11
>> s{2, :}
ans =
    11    22
>> s{2, 'a'} % same as s.a(2)
ans =
    11
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I can not use tables as the whole problem is to read the data from file into the expected structure (the second form).

Answer (score 2):

A possible simple solution would be the following:

```
fn = fieldnames(s);
for j = 1 : numel(fn)
    for k = 1 : numel(s(1).(fn{j}))
        s2(k).(fn{j}) = s.(fn{j})(k);
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Two nested loops was obvious solution, however probably not very efficient.

Comment: @rad "probably not very efficient" Why do you say this? MATLAB loops are not like they were in 1990 any more, and they are not like they are in Python. Try this, you might be surprised. I think it might even be faster than Luis' solution. However, do preallocate `s2` to be the right size before the loop. I would also see if extracting `fn{j}` before the inner loop improves speed.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Why? Because it is slow. Actually, both solutions are prety slow (the Luis' also uses quite a lot of memory. I hoped there could be solution not requiring copying data (like view for numpy ndarray since you mentioned it), or at least some vectorized form.

Comment: @rad This cannot be done without copying data. But then again, whether the output arrays hold a reference (view) or the actual value, wouldn’t matter all that much for a single value. If you have K fields and N values in each, you need to create KN matrices for your desired output. That takes space and time. Your input format is a more efficient way to store the data, even if it’s less convenient.